# Find all links <a> where <href> contains some text?

Tags: jquery, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri, and trying to get all links from a web page where the links contain `original`, using something like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(some_url))
links = doc.xpath('//a[@href*="original"]') 
p links.map {|link| link['href']}
```

The "contains" selector `*=` doesn't work in this expression, I'm getting a syntax error.

I also tried to find a `href` that equals `a[@href="link_from_page"]`, and again it's returning nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using CSS Selectors [**`[attributename*="val"]`**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Selectors/attribute_selector/attribute%2a%3Dvalue) as below :

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(some_url))
links = doc.css('//a[@href*="original"]') 
p links.map {|link| link['href']}
```

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is not valid in XPath. In order to get all links that contain a given string in the `href` attribute you should use:

```
//a[contains(@href, "original")]
```

More info [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains).

Comment: As I told you, I can't find the word `original` anywhere in the source of the page (using chrome, the url is: `view-source:http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/603-the-matrix/backdrops`). Just output the content of the `doc` variable as a string and you'll see this behaviour too.

Comment: I want to return the href of pictures, when I do expect element it shows me attributes of picture, but when I'm opening this page with nokogiri there are no pictures in html. I didn't notice that before...it's a trap. There is some other way to get links to this pictures?

Comment: Nokogiri just parses data. You're fetching data that is not the data you want. There is nothing that Nokogiri can do about it. Most likely all that data is being added dynamically by JS which Nokogiri is no able to see because it just parses data... it doesn't execute javascript. If you open the page in a browser, you're cheating, because the browser is executing the javascript on the page. That's why I linked to the `view-source:http` url. You will need to look for a library that executes JS. Most likely a headless web browser (in Java, HTMLUnit) and I think Celerity its the ruby wrapper

Comment: Thank you, all day I fought with this problem

Comment: @yozzz take a look at PhantomJS if you are into Javascript. Is pretty neat.